# Why won't chrome play .mp4 or .webm?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

Chrome says "This plugin isn't supported" even though I have both video formats. Strangely I can play HTML5 video on other websites (with the same computer/browser). I looked at the source and they have mp4 first then webm.

I tested the site with chrome from another computer and it works fine. Chrome is at the latest version on both computers.

Here is my code:

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop>
    <source src="video/ssweb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="video/ssweb.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
<source src="video/ssweb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="video/ssweb.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

Add the `muted` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes) to the `<video>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

As you explain your issue...Please check with your 'Chrome extension' in setting, it might be possible that you have any extension which is creating problem in playing the video.

Please try to stop all extensions and then try to run the page again. Hope it will work.

Comment: it plays local video fine but once it's on the server is when i get the issue (only for my site)

Comment: ok, I have seen the code, it is working fine on my system too. And what do you mean by server, I think the link which you have shared is on the server and is working fine...